# How to load dynamic chunk without vendors splitting

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import

## Quick Summary

How can I dynamically import NPM modules without generating extra `vendors~`-prefixed chunks?

## Details

### Setup

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = [{
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/index.js"),
}];
```

**index.js**

```js
__webpack_public_path__ = "dist/";

loadMoment();

function loadMoment() {
    return require.ensure(
        "moment-timezone",
        require => {
            console.log("moment loaded");
            window.MY_GLOBAL = {
                moment: require("moment-timezone"),
            };
        },
        () => {},
        "lib/moment",
    );

    /*
    // Working on an existing project with an older version of ESLint, so the preferred import()
    // trips up the linter. Using the older require.ensure to avoid linter errors, but I tested
    // with async/await and import() and I get the same result.
    window.MY_GLOBAL = {
        moment: await import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "lib/moment" * /
            "moment-timezone"
        ),
    };
    */
}
```

### Results

**This is the undesired result I'm currently getting:**

```
dist/
  lib/
    moment.js
  vendors~lib/
    moment.js
```

Note that there are 2 `moment.js` files!

- `lib/moment.js` is 16 kb and, when I examine it, contains only the `./node_modules/moment/locale` module
- `vendors~lib/moment.js` is 938kb and, when I examine it, contains over 130 modules. So, basically, all of the moment and moment-timezone modules.

**The desired result:**

```
dist/
  lib/
    moment.js
```

I would like to keep all of my NPM modules and whatever else I might want to load in a single chunk, named as I've specified, without any automatic prefixes.

### More background

I'm working on an older project that previously copy/pasted the entire minified moment and moment-timezone libraries into a JS resource named "lib/moment.js". I'd like to remove them from our codebase and generate the "lib/moment.js" file via a dynamic import. It's important to preserve the existing file name and folder structure.

The dynamic import code seemed simple enough ([webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)), but I haven't been able to find any explanation for the `vendors~` prefix or how to remove it. I can see it in the examples, of course, but that prefix is, as best I can tell, never directly addressed.

If I can't get rid of the prefix and bundle everything into just the `lib/moment` chunk, then I'm going to have to abandon this approach and just continue with the minified libraries stored in lib files (which is not ideal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

In short, you need to disable the `defaultVendors` cache group (or `vendors` prior to webpack 5):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = [{
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/index.js"),

    // ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            defaultVendors: false,
            // prior to webpack 5:
            //vendors: false,
        },
      },
    },
    // ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲
}];
```

## The what-now?

Webpack provides a [default configuration](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks) for the `optimization.splitChunks` property which includes a simple "defaultVendors" rule (or "vendors" in [v4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks)) which splits NPM modules into a separate chunk:

```js
cacheGroups: {
    defaultVendors: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        priority: -10,
        reuseExistingChunk: true,
    },
},
```

According to the docs, if you do not want to use these default cache groups, then [you have to explicitly set them to `false`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkscachegroups):

> To disable any of the default cache groups, set them to `false`.

To disable the vendors cache group, simply set it to `false` in your webpack config:

```js
cacheGroups: {
    defaultVendors: false,
},
```

### Result

```
dist/
  lib/
    moment.js
```